# modelling sensors(IMU) in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,i need to modell sensors like:gyro,acc,magnetfieldsensor in Gazebo.
Are there any examples for a sensor implemented urdf-file?
how can i modell these sensors in a urdf file,for my quadrotor?

thanks, greets

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12430/modelling-sensors(imu)-in-gazebo/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2011-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
  <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/> <!-- 0 1 0 -->
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.19"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="imu_link"/>
  </joint>


<link name="imu_link">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="0.001"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.000001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size=".001 .001 .001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<gazebo>
  <controller:gazebo_ros_imu name="imu_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_imu.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>50.0</updateRate> 
    <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
    <topicName>imu_data</topicName>
    <gaussianNoise>2.89e-08</gaussianNoise>
    <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
    <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
    <interface:position name="imu_position"/>
  </controller:gazebo_ros_imu>
</gazebo>
```

**EDIT**: This publishes a topic with the type `sensor_msgs/Imu`. To access the data via rxplot, you could use:

```
rxplot /imu_data/orientation/x
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on 2012-01-06**:
hi dimitri,thanks . i had success. But how can i plot these imu data in rxplot? it does not work.For example, i tried : rxplot imu_data/x               Can you please show me the correct syntax? greetz

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-06**:
rostopic echo "imu_data". It publishes to a topic with the name that you specify in `<topicName>`.

**Comment by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on 2012-01-05**:
hi dimitri,i edit this to my urdf,but how can i now see the imu messages? which service do i have to call?

**Comment by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on 2016-04-14**:
how do i use this in urdf?